# How to add new column with data provided by result of query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with column data_of_birth.
I want to create query where people between 0-10 will be A, and 11-18 will be B.
Something like this :

```
+-------+-----+-------+
| name  | age | class |
+-------+-----+-------+
| betty |   9 | A     |
| carl  |  12 | B     |
+-------+-----+-------+
```

The problem is how to create last column with dynamic data ?

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Comment: oki, i will try ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by Gordon Linoff, you can use [a `case` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html):

```
select 
    name,
    age,
    case
        when age between 0 and 10 then 'A'
        when age between 11 and 18 then 'B'
        else '?'
    end class
from mytable
```

Note: `age` is the name of [a built-in Postgres date/time function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), so this is not a good pick for a column name.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it was really helpfull. I have another question it is good solution when i'm using this function 3 times in one query?
 extract(YEAR from age( timestamp '2019-12-01' , date_of_birth))

Comment: @JarekSularz That's another question. Please accept this answer, and create a new one.

Comment: @JarekSularz: very likely, your database will optimize the expression and not compute it 3 times, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot and have a nice evening ;p